# Callable state supplier for Flux.generate

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-reactive

I wonder that why type of state supplier in Flux.generate in spring reactor is a Callable not a Supplier? Is it because of preventing of blocking?

Comment: why should it be supplier, please motivate

Comment: Because its responsibility is to produce an initial value for state

Comment: Yes it’s responsibility is to produce an inital value, still you havn’t motivated why a supplier interface would better suited then the callable? Are you basing your claim purly on the naming of the interface?

Comment: Then what was the reason for following inFlux class...
public static <T> Flux<T> error(Supplier<? extends Throwable> errorSupplier)
Here can't it be a Callable instead of Supplier?

Comment: It can, yes, but you havn’t motivated WHY you think it should be one or the other. As someone pointed out, and was going to be my point after i heard your argument (which consists of purely of ”it can be like this, then it should be like that”)

Comment: The difference is that one of the interface can throw a checked exception, the other can’t. Then WHY they have chosen one or the mist be because of this reason. Just because one thing CAN be replaced by another thing doesn’t mean it is right. All we have mentioned here cousld easy be looked up by googling the java docs

Answer (score 1):

Callable can throw checked Exceptions, supplier cannot.